# How can i plot an array vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to plot A vertically, I tried A.T or np.transpose(A) but it didnt work.

[image]

```py
A = np.zeros([200,1])
A[0:50] = 200
A[50:100] = 400
A[100:130] = 100
A[130:200] = 600
plt.plot(A)
```

i want to plot the figure like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
ax=plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(A, np.arange(len(A)))

ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: your output]